# Do "resolution" and "definition" differ? If so, how?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Particularly in the context of the usage of "high definition" and "resolution", as in quality of digital sound, picture, and/or video. My question is spurred by [my description](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/182519/46216) of and under an image, where I say, "Links to higher resolution, original upload." I struggled with deciding which term to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Resolution** is a technical term pertaining to the pixel count of an image, while **definition** has more to do with image clarity (seeing more details) - although in most cases they are used interchangeably in practice.

Assume you had a heavily compressed version of a screenshot, that was the same dimensions (say 1280x960) as the original but much smaller file size and also a corresponding loss in detail. This blurry version would be the same *resolution* but a lower *definition* than the original source.

In Hi-Def TVs, the increase in picture *resolution* enables output that has higher **definition** as well, hence the name.

Comment: notbad.jpg. Seems sufficient, but I'll let the question sit for maybe another day before I accept it. A source would be nice.